# Сравнение двух массивов на php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два массива

```
$m1 = array('Наташа', 'Марина', 'Катя', 'Анжела', 'Виктория');  
$m2 = array('Наташа', 'Катя', 'Анжела');
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как их правильно сравнить, чтобы в итоге вывести следующее:

```
Наташа - есть  
Марина - нет  
Катя - есть  
Анжела - есть  
Виктория - нет
```

То есть, выводить по порядку первого массива, и если имя встречается в обоих массивах, то "есть", если только в первом - то "нет".
Спасибо!
UPD Повторяться в одном массиве имена не будут по условию задачи.

Comment: `array_intersect` или просто `in_array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($m1 as $name) {
    echo $name . (in_array($name, $m2) ? 'Y' : 'N');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$m1 = array('Наташа', 'Марина', 'Катя', 'Анжела', 'Виктория');  
$m2 = array('Наташа', 'Катя', 'Анжела');

$data=array_intersect($m1, $m2);

foreach ($m1 as $key => $value) {

if($data[$key]==$value){

$name[$value]='есть';

}else{
    $name[$value]='нет';
}
}
print_r($name);
```

Comment: Вам тот же вопрос - `array_intersect` зачем?

Comment: расхожденние ))

Comment: Ну и зачем оно если можно проверить есть ли элемент первого массива во втором?

Comment: да interesect тот же цикл, можно было 2 циклами обойтись

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($m1 as $name) echo $name . (in_array($name, $m2) ? ' - есть<br/>' : ' - нет<br/>');
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]